# WebSQL silent transaction failure after about 300 txns

Tags: html, cordova, web-sql

I have an app where i am storing serialized images into websql. I first get the image list from xml, create an array of paths that lead to individual files that return jsonp ( individual files so that i can have a progress indicator). After i get the response i pass the serialized image to my db functions that then do the insert, update the image path array on success, and then kick off the next ajax request. This works fine on my local machine. in iOS (emulator and device) what happens is that at a certain point - say around the 300th image or so, all of my WebSQL transactions fail. They do so without any error code or text so i dont know whats happening there. And its the transaction that fails, not the executeSql.

The length of the serialized data averages about 45k, some get up to 6 digits. There is no pattern on the txn's that fail - the string lengths are random - the only consistent thing is that after hundreds of successful txn's everything after a certain point fails for the remaining web sql transactions (about 157 at that point).

The process is very linear: get the data via ajax - check it (timestamps, etc) - route to the insert function, then repeat.

The size of the SQL lite db on my computer is about 35mb, so I don't think I'm hitting a ceiling on the device.

This is wrapped in Cordova2.2. jQuery is used for the Ajax requests (as you will see). On my windows machine in the latest chrome with Ripple i get no errors at all - all images download.

A code sample:

```
var _SQL_DB = null;
var _SQL_DB_SETTINGS = {name:'myapp',version:'1.0',displayname:'myapp db',size:(50 * 1024 * 1024)};

// much code removed, here's the database init:
function initWebSQL(){
  _SQL_DB = window.openDatabase(_SQL_DB_SETTINGS.name, _SQL_DB_SETTINGS.version, _SQL_DB_SETTINGS.displayname, _SQL_DB_SETTINGS.size);
  _SQL_DB.transaction(
    function(tx){
      tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS IMAGES (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC, FNAME TEXT, FDATE TEXT, DATASTR TEXT)');},
    function(){ // error CB
      app.util.printToConsole('IMAGES table was not created');
    },
    function(){ // success CB
      app.util.printToConsole('IMAGES table was created succesfully');
    }
  );
}

// ... fast forward through more code....

// ajax request
function _startImgCaching(){
  $.ajax({
    url: app.host() + path,
    type:'GET',
    dataType:'JSONP',
timeout:    10000,
    error:function(xhr,status,err){
      // error logic removed
    },
    success:function(responseData,status,xhr){
      // save data
      _dbInsert(rawPath,_queue.images[0].date,responseData.data);
     // check if more need to be downloaded and stored locally
     if (_queue.length > 0){
       _queue.images.splice(0,1);
       app.util.updateProgress(_queue.length,_queue.images.length);
       setTimeout(_cacheImages,200); 
     }
});

// verify the data, check timestamps...
function _cacheImages(){
  // removed logic that checks for duplicates and routes to delete/insert methods as needed
}

// do the insert
function _dbInsert(imgName,imgDate,imgData){
  _SQL_DB.transaction(
    function(tx){
      tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO IMAGES(FNAME, FDATE, DATASTR) VALUES (?,?,?)',
        [imgName,imgDate,imgData],
        _insertSuccess,
        _insertFailure
      );
    },_transactionFailure,_transactionSuccess
  );
}

// the txn callbacks
function _transactionSuccess(tx,r){
  app.util.printToConsole('txn successful');
  if (r){
    app.util.printToConsole(r);
  }
}

function _transactionFailure(tx,e){
  // e in this case is always undefined
  app.util.printToConsole('txn failed - ' + (e ? e.message : 'no err msg available'));
}
```

Comment: iOS's websql will throw SECURITY_ERROR if storage reach around 50MB

Comment: Sounds like a storage issue. base64 encode enlarges an image by about 30%.